# Call html() on two jQuery selector objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my webpage I have two places where I need my JavaScript to write dates. How to do it in one go?

Selectors:

```
var $today = $('#today');
var $selected = $('#selected');
```

If I were to do this alternatively the easy way, I'd do:

```
$('#today, #selected').html(date);
```

But I kind of need to reuse my `#selected` jQuery object throughout my code.

The only solution I came up with so far is...

```
$([$today, $selected]).each(function(idx, obj){obj.html(date);});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you would be better off combining the two jQuery objects using [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) rather than a comma in the selector.  It's also more elegant than having to call `.each()`.

```
$today.add($selected).html(date);
```